# Refactor using partials and collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, partial-views, partials

could the following code be refactored and simplified by using the collection parameter of partials? I can't see how it could be done because of the "path" local variable being passed in.

```
<% @admins.each do |admin| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'person', :locals => { :person => admin, :path => edit_admin_path(admin) } %>
<% end if @admins %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'person', :locals => { :person => user, :path => edit_user_path(user) } %>
<% end if @users %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of [rendering collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections):

```
<%= render :partial => "person", :collection => @users + @admins %>

# in person.html.erb
path = person.admin? edit_admin_path(person) : edit_user_path(person)
```